# "cannot have number of splits n_splits=3 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=1"

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to use k-fold cross validation to compare my polynomial regression and support vector machine model. (x-axis = fuel consumption, y-axis = distance)

Below is the code I have been trying but was given an error

```
"ValueError: cannot have number of splits n_splits=3 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=1"
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = Fold(n_splits=3)
kf
```

```
x=data.iloc[:,0]
y=data.iloc[:,1]
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
```

```
for train_index,test_index in kf.split([['Distance']]):
print(train_index,test_index)
```

sample data(dataset is 2 dimensional):

```
Fuel Consumption   Distance
13.046653          444.699427
14.717947          468.604994
15.032536          464.386458
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add, random_state=42 as the last parameter to the train_test_split function

Comment: Hi, thank you for the prompt reply. I have tried but the same error message is still there.

Comment: so, Could you double the size of the sample data, just duplicate it?

Comment: okay I have figured out. thanks!

Comment: just for documenting my answer, If it is correct, please vote up

Answer (score 1):

You should have a sample data length greater than 100/test_size*10, in your case 100/30 =4 cases/rows or more